# How do I background run tomcat in docker?

Tags: docker, tomcat

I want to run Tomcat in the background.
Because I want to run the script additionally after tomcat execution.

See blow.

[ Dockerfile ]

```yaml
ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
```

[ entrypoint.sh ]

```sh
${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh run # tomcat start

echo "Hello" # I want to execute this command line. (echo "Hello" is a sample example.)
```

I want to execute `echo "Hello"`.

However, because Tomcat runs Foreground, the command does not run.

- I know that running tomcat with `catalina.sh start` will shut down the container.

**Is there any way to run tomcat in the background?**

Comment: Can you run the second command in a different container?

Answer (score 1):

The `start` and `run` commands of `catalina.sh` work alike, with the difference that `start` forks, while `run` doesn't.

However since your Docker container will stop whenever the main script exits, you'll be better off with:

```bash
# Start process in a subshell
(${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh run)&
PID=$!
# Do other stuff
echo "Hello world!"
# Wait for server to terminate
wait $PID
```